# Adding icon in particular places using ArcGIS and show data based on the location

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcglobe

I am very new to ArcGIS. Currently I am working on a project where I have to show positions of some sensors(placed in fixed locations) which are frequently(every 30 minutes) sending data to a server. I also need to show the data (2/3 values, like: temperature, PH lavel and so on) in map when anybody click to the icon of the sensor or it will automatically show the updated data table.

I have basically almost no idea about ArcGIS. So it would be better if anybody give some step by step instruction or any way so that I can accomplish the task.

Thanks

Comment: Which ArcGIS products and version are you using? How do you want users to access the dynamic data? Online in web map or using a shared mxd?

Comment: I'm using ArcGIS 10.1, and user will access data using web map.

Answer (score 1):

there is a tool called "make XY event layer" to display a points based on a table. You need a table with X coordinates, Y coordinates and your attributes.  You will need to refresh your map when there has been a change, but otherwise ArcGIS will read from the table to display the points.

the identify tools can be used to click on a sensor and display the attributes.

ArcGIS online also has tools for this.

Comment: To be honest I did not realize that [Making an Event Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000001z000000) from standalone table was dynamic.  Thanks!